# Why in a space in which compact sets have empty interior, the closure of open sets is not totally bounded?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of the theorem:

> The Baire space $\mathcal{N}$ is unique up to homeomorphism, non-empty zero-dimentional Polish space for which all compact subsets have empty interior.

It is mentioned in the proof that "since a compact set in $X$ (the space satisfies all above conditions to be homeomorphic to $\mathcal{N}$)have empty interior, it follows that the closure of $U$(a open set in $X$) is not totally bounded."

I think I may miss something obvious, and I just don't know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure of $U$ is not compact, since it has non-empty interior. It is complete, however, since it’s a closed subset of a complete space. Therefore it cannot be totally bounded, since a set is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded.

Comment: Thank you as always, sir. I forget the theorem that compactness is equivalent to completeness and total boundedness.

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace: I figured that that’s what you were missing. As always, you’re very welcome.